# How to fix error: unknown warning option [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option] issue while cross building flutter engine

Tags: flutter, cross-compiling

I am cross compiling/building flutter engine for webOS using LLVM/CLANG.
But I am getting below mentioned issue while doing the same:

---

error: unknown warning option '-Wno-unused-but-set-parameter'; did you mean '-Wno-unused-parameter'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]
error: unknown warning option '-Wno-unused-but-set-variable'; did you mean '-Wno-unused-const-variable'? [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]

---

In order to resolve this issue, do I need to update LLVM/CLANG tool chain ?
Or
Can I add '-Wno-unused-but-set-parameter' and '-Wno-unused-but-set-parameter' somewhere in existing LLVM/CLANG.

Note:- I am getting this error while building flutter engine version 2.5.0 and above. Below version 2.5.0 flutter engine is successfully built/compiled.

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.